# Can one attribute in the functional dependency be null?

Tags: database-design, database-schema, functional-dependencies, bcnf

I have a set of functional dependencies F, R = {cid, cname, bid, name, rentdate, returndate, cost} in a bookstore, there is just one table of it.

> customerid, bookid, bookname, rent and return date of this book by this person.

Obvious, it's not BCNF

but how to identify the F of non-trival functional dependencies for this?

in my opinion:

> cid -> cname
>
> bid -> bname
>
> bid, rentdate -> returndate, cid

is that ok? in the last functional dependencies, i think each order, one book be rented in a specific time, will have the unique return date and belongs to just one person

but I am also confused about this Functional dependencies, because in this table, the rentdate and returndate can also set to be null!!!

in this way, does the

> bid, rentdate -> returndate, cid

correct?

Comment: It doesn't make any sense for "rentdate" or "returndate" to be nullable. If somebody checks out a book (or rents a book, or orders a book, whatever you mean), then you know what date that happened on.

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' Turns out that often if you wink at the librarians they [don't need no stinkin'](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stinking_badges) returndates.

Comment: Re finding FDs see [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26813819/3404097). Re "bid, rentdate -> returndate, cid", at any time, given a book & a rentdate, is there just one customer and just one return date? (Q: Can a book get rented twice in a day?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Codd would simply have excluded tuples with nulls from the application of functional dependencies. As far as I know, there is no self-consistent way to cope with functional dependencies in pure SQL, using Codd's 3-value logic.

I would therefore expect most people to tell you to avoid nulls. Obviously, that is not always received as a practically useful recommendation.

There has been academic work on the topic however if you are interested. We have a paper that covers specific this issue:

> Antonia Badia and Daniel Lemire, Functional dependencies with null
>   markers, Computer Journal The Computer Journal (2015) 58 (5): 1160-1168. http://arxiv.org/abs/1404.4963